# Java generic type with wildcard causes error, but only in Eclipse 4.7.0

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, java-8, eclipse-oxygen

I am using java version 1.8.0_121. The issue I have occurs in Eclipse 4.7.0 but not in Eclipse 4.6.3. This question is more about figuring out why there is a difference and if there actually is an error than fixing the code. There is no error when compiling from gradle.

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IPredicateFactory
{
    public <P extends IPredicate<T>, T> IPredicate<T> createPredicateForClass(
            final Class<P> predicateClass);
}
```

And this code which calls the interface method:

```
public final class PredicateExecutor
{
    private IPredicateFactory predicateFactory;

    // some more code...

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private final <T> IPredicate<T> createPredicate(
            final Class<? extends IPredicate<?>> predicateClass)
    {
        assert predicateFactory != null : "Unspecified predicate factory";
        final IPredicate<?> predicate = predicateFactory.createPredicateForClass(predicateClass);
        assert predicate != null : "Predicate factory should not return a null predicate";
        return (IPredicate<T>) predicate;
    }

}
```

Eclipse 4.7.0 gives me this error:

```
The method createPredicateForClass(Class<P>) in the type IPredicateFactory is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#1-of ? extends IPredicate<?>>)
```

I'm aware that the type of the parameter in the interface (`Class<P>` with `<P extends IPredicate<T>>`) and the type of the passed object (`Class<? extends IPredicate<?>>`) are defined differently.

I can prevent the error by casting or not using a wildcard at all. But what I would like to know is:

- Is there an actual error in my code? If so, why does it even compile from gradle?
- Why does the error occur only in Eclipse 4.7.0?
- Is there anything I can do on the java/Eclipse side to prevent it?

Comment: Did you clean your project in the eclipse it doesn't work in?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Class<? extends Predicate<T>>` in the method `PredicateExecutor.createPredicate`? Though I'm not sure it's the error you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, Izuro is completely right. But I still wonder why this was not an issue earlier.